# How much is "healthy"?

Tags: word-meaning

*Healthy* in the sense of *a healthy raise in salary.* or *I bought a healthy number of books*.

Some dictionaries I looked up defines *healthy* as *fairly large* while others defines it as *great or very large* amount. So how much is *healthy* in this usage?

Comment: How can one answer such a question? You can't quantify it, and the answer will vary form one person to another. It's just high enough to really satisfy the person who gets it. And what satisfies me may not be what satisfies my next door neighbour!

Comment: As Laure suggests, *healthy* suggests not 'how much' but 'how satisfying'.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question. "Healthy" is used here in a way that may not be completely clear from a dictionary definition. I don't understand the close votes. The answer that is here now is helpful.

Comment: @Laure has the habit of posting comments that I would vote for if they were answers!

Comment: Laure, you appear to have answered your own question rather well.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes Yes, comments here are also good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the references you cite say, "healthy" in this context means "a fair amount", "a satisfying amount", or "a sufficiently large amount". Basically it means more than "just barely acceptable".

It's impossible to say exactly how much or how many this is. I can't say, "A healthy pay raise is a raise of at least $2,342.65 per year." That's one of the reasons why people use a word like "healthy". If they had a precise number in mind, they could use the number. If you were hoping or expecting to get a 3% pay raise and you got a 4% pay raise, you might say that was a "healthy raise". If inflation has been very high this year or for whatever reason you expected more, than you might say that 4% was not a healthy raise at all.

Comment: I think you've hit on it.  I think of *healthy* as *'more than might have been expected'*

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get a better feel for a word usage like this is to consult a thesaurus.  This link http://thesaurus.com/browse/healthy reveals the following under the general synonym "appreciable":

adj. easily noticed;
considerable,
apparent, 
ascertainable, 
clear-cut, 
definite, 
detectable, 
discernible, 
distinguishable, 
estimable, 
evident, 
good-sized, 
goodly, 
healthy, 
large, 
manifest, 
marked, 
material, 
measurable, 
noticeable, 
observable, 
obvious, 
perceivable, 
perceptible, 
plain, 
pronounced, 
recognizable, 
sensible, 
significant, 
sizable, 
substantial, 
tangible, 
visible.

So, perhaps the above synonyms will tell you how much "healthy" is.  :)